# JE takes jump with zero flag set to 1?

Tags: assembly, x86

The instructions executed are

```
0044B8B8  |> F745 14 000800>TEST DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+14],800
0044B8BF  |.^0F84 7BFFFFFF  JE App.0044B840
```

EBP points to `0022F38C` so +14 is `0022F3A0` which value is `00001002` while we're testing for 800 (right?) and `JE` is the same as `JZ` (right?) The register doesn't seem to get altered between the two instructions (except for EIP);

```
EAX 00000039
ECX 00000000
EDX 00000000
EBX 0022F3C9
ESP 0022F37C ASCII "XY"
EBP 0022F38C
ESI CCCCCCCD
EDI 004597E6 ASCII "XYZ"
EIP 0044B8BF App.0044B8BF
C 0  ES 0023 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
P 1  CS 001B 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
A 0  SS 0023 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
Z 1  DS 0023 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
S 0  FS 003B 32bit 7FFDD000(FFF)
T 0  GS 0000 NULL
D 0
O 0  LastErr ERROR_SUCCESS (00000000)
EFL 00000246 (NO,NB,E,BE,NS,PE,GE,LE)
ST0 empty -??? FFFF 00700070 00700070
ST1 empty -??? FFFF 00F000F0 00F000F0
ST2 empty -??? FFFF 005A0040 004E006A
ST3 empty -??? FFFF 000E0005 006000EB
ST4 empty -??? FFFF 1D0A67F9 E9A7BEF0
ST5 empty 0.0000000000000006002
ST6 empty 0.0000000000000006002
ST7 empty 0.0000000000000006002
               3 2 1 0      E S P U O Z D I
FST 4000  Cond 1 0 0 0  Err 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  (EQ)
FCW 037F  Prec NEAR,64  Mask    1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Yet still the jump is taken. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're expecting, but [`TEST` is basically an AND instruction that does not store the result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_(x86_instruction));

```
0x0800 BITWISE AND 0x1002 = 0
```

and since the result is zero, the jump is taken.

Comment: I guess a primer on assembly wasn't enough.. thanks, I'll read up some more before continuing.

Comment: It does seem little counter-intuitive... `cmp` followed by `je` makes perfect sense though.

Comment: @natli I usually go to [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly) to do quick lookups of various instructions, you may want to take a peek there if it's for you.

Answer (score 0):

JZ is the same as JE. Since the CMP instruction is subtraction without storing the result, if the two operands of CMP are equal, their difference is zero and the Z flag is set.

And, like Joachim said, TEST is AND without storing the result.